# Building Responsive Thumbnail Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to create a Responsive Thumbnail Gallery with lightboxes. The idea is to click the image and this image is going to display
on a lightbox.

I found this good [tutorial](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-build-a-responsive-thumbnail-gallery) that explains how to do
the responsive-thumbnail-gallery. I also found the colorbox plugin for having the lightbox.

My issue right now is disaligment.
Each time I add some text bellow the lines get broken.
[image]

This is a demo of what I'm trying to do.
http://jsbin.com/melaz/1

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thunk you'd maybe be better off going with Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: +1 for Masonry. You could almost implement what you're trying to do with CSS3 columns, but there are a couple of issues with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the `div`s by `height` before showing.

```
var sorted = $(".container .galleryItem").sort(function(a, b) {               
  return $(a).height() > $(b).height() ? 1 : -1;
});   

$(".container").html(sorted);
```

**http://jsbin.com/zawexubu/1**

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `float: left;` for `.galleryItem` elements, try using `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: It works kind off. Is leaving an empty space on the top it will be better.

Comment: "empty space" wasn't part of your original question.  You can probably make more CSS changes to set each `.galleryItem` element to the same height, or use jQuery to select them all and set their height directly.